# Ranking cell values across multiple grids using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, esri-grid-format

I have multiple grids, one for each month of a year. I would like to create a new grid for each month/year combination that the cell value is the percentile rank of that cells value in the grid stack.

Is there a way to iterate through the grids cell by cell, grab the values rank them and write them out to a set of clean grids using ArcPy?

Comment: It is not clear what you want.  Could you perhaps provide a small worked example to illustrate?

Answer (score 2):

There is a [rank](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z00000081000000) tool. This ranks the grids but not as a percentile rank.